# Can a subtype have relation to another subtype in a DB generalization model

Tags: database

I have a supertype entity, lets call it Item.
The Item entity has 2 subtypes Itemtype1 and Itemtype2. I suppose this is the simplest implementation so the subtypes have FK refering to PK of the supertype.

In my model the two subtypes should have 1-to-M relation between them. How should I handle that? Any issue I should keep in mind or maybe design this some other way?

It is important that i can track back to the PK of the M side of one the subtypes in the supertype entity

Answer (score 0):

If you have table1 and table2, 1:M relation can be achieved by creating a foreign key table1.table2ID which is a link to the primary key of table2. You can create as many elements in table2 as you like which have the same foreign key.

If you have table1 and you want to self-reference, then the table1.table1ID foreign key can be created, pointing to table1.ID and you can create as many elements with the same foreign key as you like. Note that in this case you have to enforce the 1:M relation with business logic.